# gitlab-ci predefined is defined in script step of deploy stage but undefined inside bash script run via 'bash -s'

Tags: bash, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

I am trying to deploy a branch other than the default (master) branch. For some reason the predefined variables are not visible inside the `roll-out.sh` script. But the `echo` statements before calling the script do print the variables correctly.

I have another script that rolls out the master branch. In this script it is able to run `docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY` with no problems.

I have tried with the branch both protected and not protected. The variables are still undefined for some reason.
What I am doing wrong here?

```
build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:20.10.12
  services:
    - docker:20.10-dind
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH # not master branch
      allow_failure: true
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/client/base:latest || true
    - docker build --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/client/base:latest --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/client:latest -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/client:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/client:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

deploy:
  variables:
    branch: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine

  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH # not master branch

  before_script:
    - apk add openssh-client
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh

  script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - echo $branch
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$DOMAIN 'bash -s' < ./script/roll_out.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sshing to another machine within your ci script I don’t think it would have accsess to the variables you are echoing out in the lines before because it’s a new session on a different machine.

You could try a few different things though to achieve what you want;

1. Try to send the variables as arguments (not great sending information to a machine through ssh).
2. Install a gitlab runner on the host you are trying to ssh to, tag this runner so it only runs the specific deployment job and then you’ll have the variables available on the host.

Comment: I would think so too, but I have another script that runs `docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY ` and that works for some reason. 

So sometimes the variables are available. 
I am not invoking a script that resides on the remote. I am basically piping commands from the alpine image.

Comment: @shivan have you declared the variables within the projects settings ci/cd page? Or is your other script in a project that has the gitlab registry enabled and this one doesn’t? 

I had thought the issue was with the variables you reference in the echo statements in deploy job because of the first part of your question.

Comment: The variables that I use are predefined variables such as CI_COMMIT_BRANCH_REF etc.

Comment: Yes - have you checked that you have the gitlab registry enabled for the project? Otherwise the variables aren’t available

Comment: Can you tell me how to check it? I think it is, but worth checking.

Comment: If it’s self hosted you’ll need admin rights to do enable it. 
You should be able to see it if you go to your project and then registries like here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/ 
You should be able to find the right instructions here for installing: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html

Comment: Oh that. Its definitely enabled. I do manage to do deploys with pulling and pushing from the gitlab container registry on the main branch. But the alternative branch it does not work for some mysterious reason.

Comment: You were right quizguy. See my answers. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by explicitly passing the environment variables to the script

`- ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$DOMAIN "CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH bash -s" < ./script/roll_out_tagged.sh`

I had another developer with lots of experience take a look at it.
He had no idea why `docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY` worked. That is what lead me to believe that all of the environment variables would be available on the remote. But seems like those three variables are some sort of exception.

Comment: It worked because the build job that you use these variables in is still within the context of a gitlab pipeline and as such has access.  Your remote machine that you ssh to is not running within the context of a gitlab pipeline and as such doesn’t have access to the variables. Sshing to another machine does not carry your environment variables with you, it opens a new terminal on the remote host that is completely separate.